# Add column to dataframe with repeat rows pre-defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Supppose I have a `dataframe` with large number of rows, such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(1000,4)), columns=list('abcd'))

df.head()
        a           b          c          d
0   0.950397    0.310118    0.068249    0.420844
1   0.428242    0.935596    0.350887    0.427620
2   0.531672    0.937594    0.964057    0.951791
3   0.697531    0.544713    0.479552    0.095523
4   0.887271    0.427256    0.719145    0.078826
```

Then I want to add a column `df['id']` where I specify that:

- the first 50 rows of column `id`  should have value  `1`,
- the next 50 rows have value `2`,
- next 50 rows value `3` and so on, until last row of `df`

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

```py
df["id"] = df.index // 50 + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            a         b         c         d  id
0    0.576101  0.848460  0.376145  0.580550   1
1    0.018544  0.505902  0.039387  0.462448   1
2    0.342677  0.185299  0.184431  0.773413   1

...

47   0.026051  0.200812  0.301835  0.481549   1
48   0.718661  0.393644  0.074783  0.710046   1
49   0.946730  0.356620  0.873066  0.473717   1
50   0.157004  0.663280  0.616098  0.590765   2
51   0.545614  0.543903  0.826963  0.131517   2
52   0.607517  0.601529  0.640343  0.404878   2
53   0.425010  0.061943  0.850835  0.164701   2
54   0.645238  0.174422  0.495790  0.780482   2

...

996  0.015375  0.341926  0.318970  0.630925  20
997  0.702063  0.242018  0.159273  0.868340  20
998  0.627403  0.334830  0.988652  0.375433  20
999  0.316490  0.374639  0.927467  0.003946  20
```